# View the SQL queries for Django queryset delete

Tags: django, django-orm

How do you view the SQL generated by Django for a `DELETE`?

When doing a `SELECT` operation on a query set, you can do this:

```
>>> qs = Entry.objects.filter(date__gt='2010-06-01')
>>> qs.query.as_sql()
('SELECT ...)
```

But I don't know how to get the SQL for what happens when I do `qs.delete()`.

It looks a bit more involved because Django "[emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)" when deleting objects.

(Background: trying to debug an IntegrityError generated by a foreign key constraint when deleting a subclassed model object.)

Comment: You can check DB error log :)

Comment: Did you solve the IntegrityError? I'm having the same problem here. Weird fact: myobject.delete() works from "manage shell" but fails from the view ???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works well enough:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries[:-10]
```

Thought the exceptions occurred before the queries were added to `connection.queries`, but they are indeed present.

Here's another method which relies on Django internals and doesn't include queries to do cascading deletes, but doesn't require executing the query:

```
from django.db.models import sql

qs = Entry.objects.filter(date__gt='2010-06-01')
query = qs.query.clone()
query.__class__ = sql.DeleteQuery
print(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try running [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) and see the queries that way.

Comment: This approach is not very general (say for errors that occur during unit testing), but thank you.